# Ordering a react map by string length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, material-ui

I have a react function that iterates through an object, and returns a button with a text string pulled from the map. What I would like to do is return the text strings in length order.

The function that builds the button is here:

```
var answersS = answerState && answerState.map(({Answer, AnswerPayload, NextQuestion}, i)=>(
                    answerArray.push(Answer),
                    answerArray.sort(function(a, b){return a.length - b.length}),
                    console.log(answerArray),
                    console.log(answerState),
                    <Grid item key={i}>
                       <Button key={i} value="check" selected={determineStyle(i)} id={i.toString()} className={classes.button} variant="outlined" color="primary">{Answer}
                       </Button>
                    </Grid>
                ))
return answersS
```

So the answerState map returns an object that looks like so:

`0: Object { Answer: "18-24", AnswerPayload: "1000AA", NextQuestion: 2, … }`

and

`1: Object { Answer: "25-50", AnswerPayload: "1000AB", NextQuestion: 2, … }`

you get the gist..

So I am trying to order the buttons to make it so the shortest "Answer" string is first.

I have first tried to create an empty array and pushed the values to them, and used sort to organise the items by string length like so:

`answerArray.push(Answer),
 answerArray.sort(function(a, b){return a.length - b.length})`

This returns the correctly sorted array:

`Array(8) [ "50+", "18-24", "25-50", "Skip to ACL objectives", "Skip to LCL objectives", "Skip to MCL objectives", "Skip to PCL objectives", "Skip to meniscus objectives" ]`

Which works fine. So I then tried to use a forEach function to iterate through this array like so:

```
answerArray.forEach((data)=>{
    <Grid item key={i}>
        <Button key={i} value="check" selected={determineStyle(i)} id={i.toString()} className={classes.button} variant="outlined" color="primary">{data}
        </Button>
    </Grid>
})
```

This should return the button objects, but in order of shortest to longest string, but it does not return anything. Any ideas why?

Comment: *'...Any ideas why?'* Sure, [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value) returns `undefined` which React ignores while rendering. So you need to basically return an array of JSX-elements, using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and it will be rendered as expected. And one more thing - swap curly braces `{` within `map()` body for normal braces `(` so anonymous callback within `map()` will return JSX.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to return the value

```
answerArray.map((data)=>{
  return (<Grid item key={i}>
    <Button key={i} value="check" selected={determineStyle(i)} id={i.toString()} className={classes.button} variant="outlined" color="primary">{data}
    </Button>
   </Grid>);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @YevgenGorbunkov

Comment: You're welcome and with arrow notation of the `map()` callback it is not necessary to use `return` explicitly, you may simply wrap your JSX into pair of braces and get rid of `{ return ... }`